# File containing dictionaries that are <class 'str'> and no commas separating the dictionaries, need to load into pandas to create csv file easily

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, generator

I've created a generator object and want to write it out into a CSV file so I can upload it to an external tool. At the minute the generator returns records as separate dictionaries but don't appear to have any commas separating the records/dictionaries and when I write out the file to a txt file and reload it back into the script it returns a <class 'str'>.

```
Class Generator declared as:
 
matches = 
{'type_of_reference': 'JOUR', 'title': 'Ranking evidence in substance use and addiction', 'secondary_title': 'International Journal of Drug Policy', 'alternate_title1': 'Int. J. Drug Policy', 'volume': '83', 'year': '2020', 'doi': '10.1016/j.drugpo.2020.102840'}
{'type_of_reference': 'JOUR', 'title': 'Methods used in the selection of instruments for outcomes included in core outcome sets have improved since the publication of the COSMIN/COMET guideline', 'secondary_title': 'Journal of Clinical Epidemiology', 'alternate_title1': 'J. Clin. Epidemiol.', 'volume': '125', 'start_page': '64', 'end_page': '75', 'year': '2020', 'doi': '10.1016/j.jclinepi.2020.05.021',}
```

Which is a result of the following generator function that compares records "doi" key within this generator object and a set of doi's from an other file.

```
def match_record():
    with open(filename_ris) as f:
        ris_records = readris(f)
        for entry in ris_records:
            if entry['doi'] in doi_match:
                yield entry
```

I've outputted this generator class `matches` by using the following code to review that the correct records have been kept as a txt file.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in matchs:
        f.write(str(x))
```

It's not a list of dictionaries nor dictionaries separated by commas that I have so I'm a bit confused about how to read/load it into pandas effectively. I want to load it into pandas to drop certain series[keys] and then write it out as a csv once completed.

I'm reading it in using `pd.read_csv` and just returns the key: value pairs for all the separate records as column headers which is no surprise but I don't know what to do before this step.

Comment: It might be returning json string, try doing ``json.loads``

Comment: Can you reduce those dicts to a small sample so we don't have to scroll to the next county to see line endings?! How do you write the dictionaries to the file? JSON?

Comment: We can't solve this problem without knowing the format of the data. If you are writing json line by line (e.g., `myfile.write(json.dumps(mydict) + "\n")`) then there is an easy solution.